# while loop not breaking with break statement in python

Tags: loops, while-loop, break

```
items=[]
price=[]
while True:
    itemsInput=input("Enter the Name of Item: ")
    if itemsInput.lower=="q":
        break
    priceInput=int(input("Enter the price of this item: "))
    items.append(itemsInput)
    price.append(priceInput)
```

In this piece of code the while true loop not breaking even if the if condition is met and break statement applies. Any idea what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: `lower` is a method, not a property, you need to change to `itemsInput.lower()` == "q"

Comment: ohh ok, didnt noticed that. Sry

Comment: and thnx for the help